# Implementing fork-merge parser for C

Tags: refactoring, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to implement a fork-merge parser for C using Java. I need to fork the parser whenever I find an #if directive. For example:

> int x = #if 3; #else 4; #endif

The above statement should be parsed as follows:

First I create a new parser for #if and read-in everything under #if statement, in the above case, reading value 3 directly wold throw a syntax error, in that case I should read back all the tokens that were already read. How do I do this?

Comment: I think you mean "int x= <nl> #if cond <nl>3; <nl>#else 4;<nl> #endif<nl>"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take any standard parser, and replicate its state on encountering an #if.  Then one version goes down the fork of the #if, the other down the fork of the #else.  (Doesn't have a #else? Pretend you saw #if cond lexemes #else #endif).

Life gets messy if the preprocessor conditionals don't occur in nice places:

```
    void p()
    {   if (x<2)
         { y =
    #if cond
       3; } else { x=
    #else
        7;
    #endif
    }
```

The parse can end up in really different states at the end of each conditional subpart. A consequence: you need to expand preprocessor conditionals so they include clean language structures.

A serious problem with this approach, is that if you fork every time you see #if, you end up with 2^N forks for N #ifs.   It is easy to find C code with dozens of conditionals; 2^24 --> 16 million so this gets out of hand fast.

So you need a way to *merge* the parses back together again when you hit the #endif.  That's not so easy; we have done this with a GLR parser but the answer is very complicated and won't fit easily here.  This technical paper discusses how to do this merge for LR parsers: http://www.lirmm.fr/~ducour/Doc-objets/ECOOP2012/PLDI/pldi/p323.pdf

There's a second complication: imagine

```
     #if  cond1
         stuff1
     #else
     #if cond2
         stuff4
     #else
         stuff5
     #endif
     #endif
```

Now you need to fork parsers inside parsers.  Worse, stuff4 has a condition, which is the conjunction of cond1 and cond2, but stuff5 has a condition of cond1 & ~ cond2.  Realistically, you're going to need to compute and retain the condition under which each parse (and generated subtree) occurs.   You'll need some kind of symbolic condition computation to do this, and you'll need to handle the case where the composed condition is entirely false specially (just skip the content).  Interestingly, our GLR solution and the above technical paper both agree that using BDDs for this is a good idea.

If you want to do refactoring, you'll need to determine the meaning of names in the presence of conditionals:

```
     #if cond1
        float x;
     #else
        char* x;
     #endif

     ...
     x=
     #if cond1
       3.7
     #else
       "foobar"
     #endif
     ;
```

This requires having a symbol table that carries conditional information with the symbols.  See my technical paper http://www.rcost.unisannio.it/mdipenta/papers/scam2002.pdf for details on how to approach this.

To do refactoring, you're going to need control and data flow analysis on top of all this.

Check out my bio for a tool where we are attempting to do all this.  We have the conditional parsing part done right, we think.  The rest is still up in the air.